# Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions

Tags: model-view-controller

This part of code is not working

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.Registrations.Count())
         </td>
```

and throws an error

> [InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.]

But this part of code below is working as a charm.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
           @item.Registrations.Count()
        </td>
```

Is there anybody who can explain why is so?

Answer (score 30):

I'd think it's because you're using `modelItem => item.Registrations.Count()`. `DisplayFor` wants an expression that refers to a member of your model, not a function on a member's method as the model binder wouldn't know how to serialize the data on the way back (i.e. after a form post).

EDIT: I'd weirdly had the same error but for a completely different reason which turned out to be that the DateTime needed to be nullable

Comment: This is correct. The problem is that you are using the `Count()` method as parameter for `DisplayFor`, which is not allowed. The parameter to `DisplayFor` must be a property or field.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this error message occur when attempting to generate a control for an inappropriate data type, for example, when trying to use (in VB.NET syntax):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(model) model.IsLotTraced)
```

Where `IsLotTraced` is declared as

```
Public Property IsLotTraced As String
```

The error goes away when it's changed to

```
Public Property IsLotTraced As Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, After a form post think it's because you're using modelItem=>item.Registrations.Count(). DisplayFor is an expression that refers to a member of your model, not a function on a member's method as the model binder wouldn't know how to serialise the data on the way back.