# @Html Displayfor throwing exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I tried something like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => (item.Name + "@" + item.Department))
```

I get "InvalidOperationException" (Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.)

Both the members are strings, I thought this should work...

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925728/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892248/get-a-template-error-when-i-try-to-do-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because `DisplayFor` accepts an `Expression` which is `Expression<Func<TModel,TReturn>>` and not a delegate `Func<TModel, TReturn>`. So you can't mix it with random C# code as it is not a delegate.

To get what you want, you can use this (odd syntax I know - because you have to escape the `@`):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Name)@:@@@Html.DisplayFor(item => item.Department)
```

Comment: It may just be variable name issue. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the below links.I Hope this will solve your problem.

[Get a template error when I try to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892248/get-a-template-error-when-i-try-to-do-this)

[Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9925728/templates-can-be-used-only-with-field-access-property-access-single-dimension)

Comment: do those links solve the problem? If so could you add why you think they solve the problem to your answer..?